# Typoscript use constant in include_typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Can we use constant variable in include_typoscript

In my constants.txt file

```
filepaths{
    # cat=FLUIDPAGES/settings; type=text; label=Pfad zu den Templates
    defaultTemplateRootPath = typo3conf/ext/defaulttemplate/
}
```

In my setup.txt file

```
Include Page Template
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE: {$filepaths.defaultTemplateRootPath}fluid.txt">
```

I just need to use {$filepaths.defaultTemplateRootPath} in my setup file for include typoscript file, If yes it's very helpful for me and I could add multiple themes/templates in multi - Domain site.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I believe in TYPO3 6.2, the include directive will allow relative paths, which would ease the situation.

Comment: Yeah, Jost! include all my ts using DIR instead of FILE individual. But be ensure all file extension with .ts.
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="DIR: EXT:defaulttemplate/Configuration/TypoScript" extensions="ts">

Answer (score 3):

According to https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/Includes.html you can't use constants in the INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT part:

> It is processed BEFORE any parsing of TypoScript

But you could use the following method in your localconf.php

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTypoScript('myKey', 'setup', '<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:' . $filePath . 'fluid.txt">');
```

Comment: the link is dead ^^